# Problem with creating a directory in Java

Tags: java, directory

I am trying to create a directory in Java. I think I have provided correctly all necessary things so that I make the directory, but it is not created. You can see from my code below and the corresponding output that every element from which I compose the path of the new directory should be correct and valid.
It seems, however, that `tDir.mkdir();` is not doing anything, and therefore the `success` variable is always `false`. I cannot understand why. Thank you in advance.

```
System.out.println("experimentDir: " + experimentDir);
System.out.println("item.getName(): " + item.getName());
System.out.println("dirName: " + dirName);
String tDirStr = experimentDir + "/" + item.getName() + "All/" 
    + dirName + "DataAll";
System.out.println("tDirStr: " + tDirStr);
File tDir = new File(tDirStr);
if (tDir.exists()) {
      System.out.println("EXISTS!!!");
} else {
      boolean success = tDir.mkdir();
      if(success) {
            System.out.println("Dir created");
      } else {
            System.out.println("No dir created!");
      }
```

Output:

```
 experimentDir: /home/Documents/datasets/test-experiments
 item.getName(): PosNegReviews
 dirName: test
 tDirStr: /home/Documents/datasets/test-experiments/PosNegReviewsAll/testDataAll
 No dir created!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create multiple (nested) directories you should use [mkdirs()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) (note the **s**).

Answer (score 1):

you may be needing to create any parent directory that dont exist. try File.mkdirs().

Comment: And double check directory permissions along the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path="c:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4";
        File dir=new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

above code will create dir4 inside C:\dir1\dir2\dir3. If parent folder does not exist, then it will also create.